# Admob interstitial ad is shown even after the activity is closed

Tags: android, admob

I am displaying an interstitial full screen ad as my fragment starts. Problem is even if i close the app the ad will load.  As the app is loaded on a separate activity and there is no method that can be called to stop the ad load as fragment is exited. How can i stop ad being and shown after and app is closed.